# Rest API doesn't load data quick enough before the route is shown using vue.js and vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Using Vue.js with vue-router in unison with WP Rest API 2.
When I switch to a route I see the div appear that should hold the content, and then the content finally loads. I also get this error:

[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "content.content.rendered": TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

The content will load on a computer eventually, even with the error, but on mobile the content doesn't show up at all. This is my method do grab a specific page. I have tried using nextTick but couldn't get it to function correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if you need more information.

```
<template>

<div> 
<div class="animated cateringWrap">
  <h1>{{ content.title.rendered }}</h1>
  {{{ content.content.rendered }}}
</div>
</div>

</template>



<script>
export default {
data() {
  return {
    content: []
  }
},


ready: function(){
  this.loadContent();
},

methods: {
  loadContent: function() {
    this.$http.get('http://localhost/t/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/82').then(function(response){
        this.content = response.data;
    });
     
 
  }
}

} 

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend posting the code here, instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Use vue-router's data hook.

http://router.vuejs.org/en/pipeline/data.html

```
route: {
  data: function (transition) {
    return this.$http.get(...);
  }
}
```

Then, in the template:

```
<div v-if="$loadingRouteData">Loading ...</div>
<div v-else>Your current HTML.</div>
```

Comment: I'm calling the routes in index.js - Not sure where I would add your code.
'
router.map({
  '/home': {
    component: Home
  },
'

Comment: @4ndy The `route: {}` block goes in your `.vue` component file. It's a block like `ready` or `methods` are.

Comment: That worked well but the transition effect has vanished. I'm using animate.css bounce effect. What you've essentially done is given a pre-loader screen. Thanks for that.

I'm having even more errors now though, and still the same error I'm trying to get rid of:

** [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "content.content.rendered": TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined **

The other errors I'm getting now:

Comment: [Vue warn]: You are setting a non-existent path "request" on a vm instance. Consider pre-initializing the property with the "data" option for more reliable reactivity and better performance.
[Vue warn]: You are setting a non-existent path "data" on a vm instance. Consider pre-initializing the property with the "data" option for more reliable reactivity and better performance function) 
[Vue warn]: You are setting a non-existent path "status" on a vm instance. Consider pre-initializing the property with the "data" option for more reliable reactivity and better performance function)

Comment: You'd want to make anything that references the properties of `content` within the `v-else`. You're getting some of those errors because content is `[]` before the GET call completes.

Comment: None of the code you've shown says `status` or `request` anywhere.

Comment: I haven't played with animations in vue-router but http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#transition-mode would seem to indicate they're possible.

Comment: Yeah transition animation work. I just keep getting this error even though the content does show eventually. Live example: http://tananola.com/

Comment: I'm not seeing the `route:` block in your `build.js` anywhere.

Comment: Should be there now

Comment: The reason why the Menu and Location page don't throw an error is because all the content is static html from within the template files. Anything calling WP data throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix is to prevent Vue from trying to access the object property:.
First set the initial `content` value to `null`, based on your example, there is no reason to set is as an empty array. Looks like it will get assigned an object from your response data. Then, in your view, just do this:

```
{{{ content ? content.content.rendered : null }}}
```